# QEMU - (Index=0) exists

Tags: windows, virtualization, qemu

I'm getting this `index=0 exists` error when I try to run qemu with this specific lines:

Command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 `
-cpu "Penryn-v1" `
-boot order=c,once=d `
-m 4096 `
-smp 2,sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2,maxcpus=8 `
-drive file="F:\Maquinas Virtuais\VMs\Kali.img",media=disk `
-drive file="F:\Maquinas Virtuais\ISOs\kali-linux-2021.4a-installer-amd64.iso",media=cdrom
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'F:\Maquinas Virtuais\VMs\Kali.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
F:\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: ,media=disk: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
PS F:\Maquinas Virtuais\VMs>
```

If I'd remove the part of the `media=`, then QEMU starts but it's looks like it can't find the files ( the `.img` and `.iso` files do not load on QEMU)

Command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 `
-cpu "Penryn-v1" `
-boot order=c,once=d `
-m 4096 `
-smp 2,sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2,maxcpus=8 `
-drive file="F:\Maquinas Virtuais\VMs\Kali.img" `
-drive file="F:\Maquinas Virtuais\ISOs\kali-linux-2021.4a-installer-amd64.iso"
```

I tried to explicit tell qemu the `bus,unit and index` on the `-drive` flag, but the error is the same everytime

I managed to start QEMU by removing the `-drive` line and issuing the `-hda` for the `.img disk` and `-cdrom` for the `.iso cdrom`.

Command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 `
-cpu "Penryn-v1" `
-boot order=c,once=d `
-m 4096 `
-smp 2,sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2,maxcpus=8 `
-hda "F:\Maquinas Virtuais\VMs\Kali.img" `
-cdrom "F:\Maquinas Virtuais\ISOs\kali-linux-2021.4a-installer-amd64.iso"
```

Anyone knows why QEMU issue the error that `index=0 exists` when trying to run QEMU with the `-drive` flag with the specific atribute of the `media=` being passed? Even without the `media=`, QEMU do not starts as intended, as it can't find the files to boot the cdrom or HD.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully. For instance,

```
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

If you know for certain this is RAW image, tell that QEMU for it to not to try autodetection: `file=...,format=raw`. The warning will go away together with restrictions on block 0.

The `media` attribute has nothing to do with this. It tells QEMU how to present the storage into the VM, not how it is backed in the host.

Comment: Thank  you. It helped me to solve the problem with the index=
I still got the error, even with the format=raw.
So i realized that maybe the full path to the IMG/ISO could be causing problems, so I got into the directory and started QEMU just with the name of the files.
Maybe the spaces or quotes on the declaration of the file= can't be read... Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: Are you still getting the exact same error?

Comment: No, after adding the "index=" and changing the path to the files it is working fine.
Also,renaming the directory structure so that there are no spaces in the name of the directories solved the problem in the "file=" value part, as that part doesn't seem to understand spaces in the value.